# Inserting jQuery function into Wordpress single page with embedded PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to insert a jQuery function into a Wordpress page that connects to a MySQL database that returns a large list of items for an autocomplete text input in a form.  It's not working.

Here is my function in it's own .js file in a js folder I created within the file structure of the theme I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(

    var availableTags = [

    <?php

    $dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "db_name", "db_name") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("db_name") or ("Database not found");

    $query = "SELECT col FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "\"". $row['col']."\", ";
    }

    // $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( $result."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    mysql_close($connect);

    ?>
    ];

    $( "#id" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags

    });

)});
```

These are the external links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is what I've inserted in my theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' , 11 );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'function_name', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/function_name.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.0',
        true

    );
}
```

Comment: Could explain what you mean by "not working"? Errors, wrong format, ....

Comment: You can't run php code in a js file. Server won't compile it

Comment: You're including jquery directly, and then adding it as a requirement of your enqueued script.  Take out the links, wordpress doesn't need them.   Plus, as @charlietfl said, you can't compile php from inside a js form, as php is compliled server side and js is compiled during runtime.

Comment: This code works locally, with PHP embedded inside the jquery which is embedded inside <script> tags, all of which is embedded in the <head> of the page ...

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but what are some solutions?  Any links to tutorials or visuals?

Answer (score 0):

You can not run `php` code into javascript file. So what you should do:

1. You should use ajax, learn at first how to use ajax in wordpress. Reference example: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/
2. Wordpress already has database connection, you shouldn't reconnect. Just you will do quesry only. This is the class reference how will query and other things query related in wordpress : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
3. You have mentioned that autocomplete in input filed, so you should use `onkeyup`, `onkeypress` similar event in to the js snippet.

However, you should learn overall things separately and then go to execute as your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT col FROM table");
foreach ($results as $tableResult)
{
    echo $tableResult->col;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I get a text field in an HTML form to autopopulate these values when the user starts typing?